# Laravel HTMLPurifier only working on items copy and pasted in as rich text

Tags: php, laravel, sanitization, htmlpurifier

Working with HTMLPurifier for Laravel I came across an issue.

Taking this piece of code from a forum as the example:

```
<a href="http://www.extramileleeds.co.uk/" class="bbc_url" 
 title="External link" rel="nofollow external"
 >http://www.extramileleeds.co.uk/</a>
```

That on the forum is simply shown as the link. I am using a `contenteditble` div for my texteditor and using `HTMLPurifier` to strip out *everything* except for image tags and their source.

My aim is for users to be able to go onto forums, and copy and paste anything. Literally straight off the page so all the images and links etc and I clean the whole thing up into plain text and images.

This works, until you directly insert some HTML for example.

So instead of copy and pasting from the page, if I copy the source code above into my editor it is not touched by `HTMLPurifier`.

Comment: Show us a sample of how do you send the text to the server, and how the server handles the input.

Comment: Fixed it, shall answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issues was because before posting the form, I transferred the data from the contentEditable div to a text input via jQuery. The text transferred could only be set via .val() and the string was being encoded into special chars.

To fix, I changed the text input to a textarea and switched the jQuery to use .html() instead.